# S3 like signed url for nginx file serving

Tags: docker, nginx

So , I have setup my project and I am planning to self serve my files from my server. Currently I have two folders from where I want users to access files , 1. Media folder and another is static folder . I wanna set up signed urls just like S3 provides so that one cannot bruteforce and get all my files from the server's either folders. Also I want to make it so that I can handle uploading of files directly from nginx rather than through my application.

Comment: Is this a problem description or a project description for Upwork.com? What have you tried so far? Show us and tell the community where you get stuck and maybe somebody will help you out.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for lack of description. But have figured out a better way . One person suggested checking out [minio](https://min.io) and it fit in nicely to what was required.

Answer (score 2):

For the signed URLS - need to generate them with your application. Then you have two options:

1. Serve the files with your application after validating the URL is valid
2. Serve the files with nginx but do the validation/authorization with your app. This is what you need:
   http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request

For the upload part the situation is similar, you can either:

1. Handle uploads with your app
2. Use nginx-upload-module and handle the authorization only with your app

I would definitely recommend handling all uploads within your app, it is just simpler.